# Inverse image of ideal under a homomorphism of rings is generated by inverse images of generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

I am curious about the statement mentioned in the title and tried to prove it. The proof looks fine to me but it would be nice if someone could confirm it to be correct.

Let $\phi: R\to S$ be a homomorphism of rings and let $I=(g_1,\dots, g_r)\subset S$ be an ideal. Then, $$\phi^{-1}(I)=(\phi^{-1}(g)\mid g\in I)=(\phi^{-1}(\sum a_ig_i)\mid a_i\in S)=(\sum\phi^{-1}(a_i)\phi^{-1}(g_i)\mid a_i\in S)\\ =(\sum b_i\phi^{-1}(g_i)\mid b_i\in R)=(\phi^{-1}(g_1),\dots,\phi^{-1}(g_r)).$$

Feel free to point at any mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Looks correct to me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems essentially boiling down to $\phi$ being possibly not invertible:

- $\phi^{-1}(g)$ does not make sense if $g$ has more than one preimage.
- Since $\phi$ is not given surjective, for $g$ not in the image of $\phi$,$\phi^{-1}(g)$ does not make sense.

Therefore, you need to change your hypotheses. Making $\phi$ surjective, and letting $\phi^{-1}(a)$ denote the set of all preimages of $a$ rather than a single one, should make your proof work.

Comment: I see, thanks for pointing out. So it might happen that $\phi^{-1}(I)$ has more generators than $I$?

Comment: Yes , it could happen

Comment: To make examples yourself, consider a map from a non-principal ideal domain to a principal ideal domain, such that the kernel is a non-principal ideal.